# How to flag stuff as dirty just as `setNeedsDisplay`

Tags: ios, core-animation

I want to know how to implement a similar logic to `setNeedsDisplay`.

My understanding:

- someone calls `setNeedsDisplay`
- drawing will be timed to happen at the end of the run loop

I would like a similar logic where I'm able to flag things as dirty and update them before drawing happens.

Comment: How do you draw those things?

Comment: It is not about drawing. It is about text calculation.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to calculate text at the end of the run loop? Or you just want to stack up some text changes, and then commit them all together?